# exclamation mark in action output when using "load data infile" code

Tags: mysql

I am new to the MySQL Workbench.

There is an action output screen and when I run the query, it shows as a green tick when successful or a red X icon for failure.

But when I use below, it comes with a yellow exclamation mark as output.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/data_apr.csv'
INTO TABLE a_manifest_base_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The data is loaded correctly (it seems!). Are there any concerns that it's not showing a green tick but instead a yellow exclamation mark?

Comment: Unusual not to have a lines terminated by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow triangle with an exclamation mark means there is a **WARNING**. You can read the warning message by hovering on the icon.

In most cases, there should be no concerns.